# uncertainty in a best fit gradient with error bars

Tags: python, scipy

I want to obtain a best fit gradient to my data, which I have been able to do using scipy.stats.linregress.

But is there an equivalent in which the error in the fit takes into account the error bars on the data?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe check out [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/)?